# How to use delayElements() with Flux merge?

Tags: java, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I am following a tutorial and I believe my code is same with the instructor's one but I did not understand why **delayElements()** is not working.

Here is the caller method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    FluxAndMonoGeneratorService fluxAndMonoGeneratorService = new FluxAndMonoGeneratorService();
    fluxAndMonoGeneratorService.explore_merge()
            .doOnComplete(() -> System.out.println("Completed !"))
            .onErrorReturn("asdasd")
            .subscribe(System.out::println);
}
```

If I write the method without delay elements as:

```
public Flux<String> explore_merge() {

        Flux<String> abcFlux = Flux.just("A", "B", "C");
        Flux<String> defFlux = Flux.just("D", "E", "F");

        return Flux.merge(abcFlux, defFlux);
    }
```

Then the output in the console is(as expected):

```
00:53:19.443 [main] DEBUG reactor.util.Loggers$LoggerFactory - Using Slf4j logging framework
A
B
C
D
E
F
Completed !

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 1s
```

But I want to use **delayElements()** to test **merge()** method as:

```
public Flux<String> explore_merge() {

        Flux<String> abcFlux = Flux.just("A", "B", "C").delayElements(Duration.ofMillis(151));
        Flux<String> defFlux = Flux.just("D", "E", "F").delayElements(Duration.ofMillis(100));

        return Flux.merge(abcFlux, defFlux);
    }
```

And nothing happens, not onComplete nor onErrorReturn and the output is just nothing:

```
0:55:22: Executing ':reactive-programming-using-reactor:FluxAndMonoGeneratorService.main()'...

> Task :reactive-programming-using-reactor:generateLombokConfig UP-TO-DATE
> Task :reactive-programming-using-reactor:compileJava
> Task :reactive-programming-using-reactor:processResources NO-SOURCE
> Task :reactive-programming-using-reactor:classes

> Task :reactive-programming-using-reactor:FluxAndMonoGeneratorService.main()
00:55:23.715 [main] DEBUG reactor.util.Loggers$LoggerFactory - Using Slf4j logging framework

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 1s
```

What is the reason for this ? (I mean at least onError I am expecting but nothing...)

note: **mergeWith()** is also not working with this **delayElements()**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`subscribe` is not blocking operation and `delayElements` will be scheduled on another thread (by default `parallel` Scheduler). As result your program exits before elements are emitted. Here is a test

```
@Test
void mergeWithDelayElements() {
    Flux<String> abcFlux = Flux.just("A", "B", "C").delayElements(Duration.ofMillis(151));
    Flux<String> defFlux = Flux.just("D", "E", "F").delayElements(Duration.ofMillis(100));

    StepVerifier.create(Flux.merge(abcFlux, defFlux))
            .expectNext("D", "A", "E", "B", "F", "C")
            .verifyComplete();
}
```